# How do I avoid hard coding my values for my conditions in this program to print out a Christmas tree?

Tags: python

In my program, I don't know how to make it so that I can print out this Christmas tree without hardcoding values.

```
z=20
x=1
for i in range(9):
    print(' ' * z + '+' * x + ' ' * z)
    x += 4
    z -= 2
    if z==14 or z==11  or z== 8 or z== 5 or z ==2:
    z+=3
    x-=6
    continue
```

Comment: Christmas tree...?

Comment: Yeah I'm a beginner with Python, and I'm trying to write a program that can print out something like a christmas tree.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `z % 3 == 2`?

Comment: Just define them, so they are not hard-coded... Take all your values, give them meaningful names, and define them before the loop

Comment: you can use `sys.argv` to get values which you use when you start it as `python script.py 20 1`

Comment: `continue` at the end of `for`-loop is useless.

Comment: Thank you so much! The z % 3 ==2 thing worked.

Comment: Okay, I will delete it.

Comment: Suggestion: Change your print to a simpler: `print('{:^41}'.format('+' * x))`, which centers the text in 41 columns, then you can get rid of the `z` variable.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
height = 80
background_width = height * 2
tree_parts = 1
for i in range(height):
    half_background_width = background_width // 2
    background = half_background_width * " "
    tree = tree_parts * "+"
    print(f"{background}{tree}{background}")
    tree_parts += 4
    background_width -= 4
    if (background_width - 4) % 3 == 0:
        background_width += 6
        tree_parts -= 6
```

Changes:

- [Rename the variables](https://chrismdp.com/2012/09/the-power-of-good-naming/) to make it more clear what is happening.
- Use [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) to to display each line.
- Use [modulo](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) operator to calculate the break point where the tree gets narrower.
- Remove [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) from the end of the for loop as this is default.
- Use the height of the tree to calculate the desired width, to make larger trees fit.

Note: a lot of these modifications were mentioned in the comments as well by others.